# Plot with three functions and three parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, distributions, parametric-functions

I think my code doesn't have any problem but the program shows me this error and I'm confused!

> Plot::argr: Plot called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.

```
 a = 1; l = 2;
    w1[x_, c_, theta1_] := x^c + theta1;
    f[x_] := ( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a];
    mesi = Integrate[x*f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}];
    mesi1 = Integrate[(x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]), {x, 0, Infinity}];
    fw1[x_, c_, theta1_] := ((x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]))/(Integrate[(x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]), {x, 0, Infinity}]);
    DH1[x_, c_,theta1_] := ((Integrate[(x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]), {x, 0,Infinity}])/((Integrate[(x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]), {x, 0, Infinity}]) +theta1))*(((x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/ Gamma[a]))/(Integrate[(x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]), {x, 0, Infinity}])) + (theta1/ (Integrate[(x^c + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]), {x, 0, Infinity}]) + theta1)*(( l^a*x^(a - 1)*Exp[-l*x])/Gamma[a]);
 Manipulate[Plot[DH1[x, c, theta1]], {x, 0, 100}, , {c, 0, 10}, {theta1, 0, 10}]
```

My plot doesn't run. I want to run this function with on the horizontal axis, I want to have theta.

Comment: `Plot[DH1[x, c, theta1]]` is the problem. what range do you want to plot? see `Plot` [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) examples.

Comment: great, thank you very much. I want the prices to be from zero to infinity.

Comment: `Plot[{`functions`},{`variable and range`}]` expects a single variable because it is a 2D plot. If you want to plot several functions, they must all depend on the same variable. The way you have written it, it seeks to calculate one function but the Plot command does not know what to use on the horizontal axis. It is not clear to me what your goal is.

Comment: Good evening Nicholas on the horizontal axis, I want to have theta. Thank you for your time you give a idea!

Answer (score 0):

Right bracket in the wrong place?

Perhaps

Plot[DH1[x, c, theta1]], {x, 0, 100}

should be

Plot[DH1[x, c, theta1], {x, 0, 100}]